# minutes in HH.MM format

Tags: oracle, time

I am using the following query

```
(24 * extract(day from (sysdate - c.LOADING_TIME) day(9) to second))
       + extract(hour from (sysdate - c.LOADING_TIME) day(9) to second)
       + ((1/100) * extract(minute from (sysdate - c.LOADING_TIME) day(9) to second)) -
required_time/60
```

Now I am getting data as something like 6.76. The issue is I am not converting the required_time in HH.MM. How to do this?

p.s. Note that required_time denotes minutes (integer) I need output as 5.45 which would mean 5 hours and 45 min

Comment: What is the data type of c.LOADING_TIME?  What are you trying to accomplish.  You explain what you don't want, but don't really explain what you do want.

Comment: LOADING_TIME is date. I want this piece:- (sysdate - loadingtime) - required_time. I have converted the first two in HH.MM format but not able to do for required_time whose datatype is integer (its minutes)

Comment: I think its `HHMI` not `HHMM`. `MM` is for months.

Answer (score 0):

To have `EXTRACT` work you will have to convert the fields using `TO_TIMESTAMP()` so that the correct timestamp appears. Also, i think you are talking about `MI` not `MM` since `MM` means Month not Minutes. Something like this-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JAN-2005 19:15:26','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM dual;
```

With date fields, it would be-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) FROM dual;
```

In your query, the `hour from (sysdate...)` and `minute from (sysdate...)` are probably returning `0`. However, for `day` it would work.

Comment: the first part of the query extract... is working fine. for ex. say it returns 10.35. Now I want to subtract that with required_time which i have in minutes. I tried reqd_time/60 but that gives me like 10.85 which is not in HH.MM.

Comment: your `extract day` is fine, but I am a little skeptical about the `extract hour` and `extract minute`. Can you just run `select extract(hour from (sysdate - <loading time value>) day(9) to second) from dual;` and see what it returns?

Comment: returns a integer - hour. guess that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want the difference expressed in hours and minutes.  I would do this with simple arithmetic:

```
select trunc((sysdate - c.LoadingTime)*24) as hours,
       trunc(mod((sysdate - c.LoadingTime)*24*60, 60)) as minutes
from . . .
```

You can format this into a string:

```
select to_char(trunc((sysdate - c.LoadingTime)*24), '00')||':'+
       to_char(trunc(mod((sysdate - c.LoadingTime)*24*60, 60)), '00')
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have `LOADING_TIME  DATE` and `REQUIRED_TIME  INTEGER`, and you're trying to determine the difference between the actual time to load something (SYSDATE - LOADING_TIME) and the standard load time (REQUIRED_TIME).

If I've got that right, try the following:

```
WITH e AS 
  (SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL((SYSDATE - LOADING_TIME), 'DAY') -
          NUMTODSINTERVAL(REQUIRED_TIME, 'MINUTE') AS ELAPSED 
     FROM YOUR_TABLE_HERE) 
SELECT TRIM(CASE
              WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ELAPSED) < 0 THEN '-'
              WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ELAPSED) < 0 THEN '-'
              ELSE ' '
            END ||
            TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ELAPSED)), '09')) || '.' || 
            TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ELAPSED)), '09')))
  FROM e;
```

`NUMTODSINTERVAL` is Oracle's function for converting a scalar value such as your REQUIRED_TIME into an INTERVAL, which can then be used in calculations involving DATEs and such.  Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions117.htm).

Hopefully this will make things a bit simpler.

Share and enjoy.

---

EDIT: Corrected the EXTRACT calls.  Added conversion of the result of SYSDATE - LOADING_TIME to an interval.  Included sign handling.

Comment: says ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic on ELAPSED